# using js.coffee append in rails for render partial

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript

helo guys, im new in ruby on rails and i want use rander partial with js.coffee but after use append i have problem, after click submit i want show my view but there nothing happened just show my code

in here my code

my.js.coffe

```
    $(document).ready ->
      $('#results').empty()
      $('.check').click ->
       $('#results').empty()
       $('#results').html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial =>'result').html_safe %>")
      return
    return
```

and here my view

> index.html.erb

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div id="results"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

and in here my view after click show my code
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDqM0.png)

Answer (score 0):

I would need more context to know if everything is ok.

But as a first comment, I assume you're not using an updated Rails version, so you need to add `.erb` extension to your js file:
`my.js.coffee.erb` instead of `my.js.coffee`. Otherwise Rails doesn't know it needs to embed the template there.

If everything else is fine, then it should work with that change.

Comment: im using rails version 5.1.6, and after add extension `.erb` i got error undefined method `render'

Comment: We need more context then. The absolute path to all your template files included in the issue for example.